# Profile Memory useage for my Windows Mobile Application

Tags: memory-management, windows-mobile, compact-framework, profile

Is there a tool that allows me to profile the memory usage for my Windows Mobile Application.

My app has a section of code that is right up against the limit of the total memory.  I have tried to setup my code so that the references to large objects go out of scope before new references are needed.

But I need a way to see if it is working.

So... any one know a way to do this (on Windows Mobile 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the NetCF CLR Profiler, which is part of [the CF 3.5 PowerToys](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C8174C14-A27D-4148-BF01-86C2E0953EAB&displaylang=en)?  It provides history of all object allocations, their sizes, owners, deallocations, etc.

**EDIT**

Usage of the profiler [is outlined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

u can use dotTrace memory profiler to profile Windows mobile application it gives better results for memory information